# CSV file output - insert an additional column at the start

Tags: php

I have a php script that generates writing data from an html form to a csv file. Everything is alright.
I need to edit my current php script to write a numbered list to a csv file.
Current php script writes to csv in format:
Date and time of recording, Name, Date of birth, etc ..
Required csv enrollment format:
record number, date and time, Name etc ...
More in the source code.
Can anyone advise? Please?

```php
$content = "Datum registrace; Jméno; Příjmení; Den narození; Měsíc narození; Rok narození; Ulice čp; Město; PSČ; Stát; Telefonní č; Číslo ŘP; Skupiny ŘP; E-Mail; Místo školení\n";   

$content .= "$dat_reg; $jmeno; $prijmeni; $den_nar; $mes_nar; $rok_nar; $ulice_cp; $mesto; $post_code; $country; $tel_nr; $nr_rp; $str; $email; $lokalita\n" ; 

$file_name = fopen("registrace.csv","a") ;     
fwrite($file_name, $content . "\n") ;   

fclose($file_name);
```

Comment: Great. The problem was solved. Thank you all.

Comment: It's not clear what the question is here.  What in your script is not currently working?

Comment: The described script generates a record into the csv file data in the following order: Date and time + First name + Last name + Date of birth + month of birth + year of birth etc ...
I need to modify this script to add the record ID (record number = record 1, record 2, record 3, etc.) to each record beginning.

Comment: I've updated the question title (though it will need to be reviewed before it shows up).  You might want to consider making the question a bit clearer too, but it was the title that was the most misleading part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Mehmet's answer, if you want to append to a file you add the FILE_APPEND flag.

```
file_put_contents('registrace.csv', $content."\n", FILE_APPEND );
```

Answer (score 2):

If u want with oop

```
$content .= "$dat_reg; $jmeno; $prijmeni; $den_nar; $mes_nar; $rok_nar; $ulice_cp; $mesto; $post_code; $country; $tel_nr; $nr_rp; $str; $email; $lokalita\n" ; 


$file = new SplFileObject('registrace.csv', 'w');


$file->fputcsv($content);
```

Be careful

```
$file = new SplFileObject('registrace.csv', 'w');
```

Look at the second Param if w(write) if a(append),

If you array write to CSV file,you should following code

```
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$file = new SplFileObject('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    $file->fputcsv($fields);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way.

```
file_put_contents("filename.txt",$content);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$content` rather than `"content"`?